Upwards opening container
i'm relatively new to wordpress and have to build a small e commerce site. For a specific portion of it I have to make an "upwards opening" product card (for example in a 3 x 2 grid the initial ccard would be placed in the lower middle portion), so that when the user clicks it, it opens upwards and takes up all the horizontal space of the 3 columns living above it. I've got no idea how to do this and the communities help would be greatly appreciated.
